# play separate animations in threejs

Tags: animation, three.js, 3dsmax

I exported a model(with several animations) from 3ds max and ultimately translated it into JSON.  However, all of my animations are smashed into one animation.  Is there a way in threejs to only play a certain range of frames , or do I need to do an export from 3ds max for each individual animation? 
Thanks,
David

Comment: Bump. Also looking for the solution :(

Answer (score 0):

there are two types of animations.
I use mesh morph one when exporting from Blender. My resulting json has this line:

```
"morphTargets" : [{ "name": "animation_000000", "vertices": [...
```

then I load it using MorphAnimMesh:

```
mesh = new THREE.MorphAnimMesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials ) );
```

after loading I set idle animation by default:

```
mesh.duration = 4000; //4 seconds whole animation?
mesh.setFrameRange(1,50);
```

then on some event i just change animation range like this:

```
mesh.setFrameRange(51,80);
```

if you use bones and skins animation, your json model ends up with lines

```
"animations" : [...
"bones": [...
```

i havent used that one, so try this tutorial:
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/webgl-with-threejs-models-and-animation--net-35993

also this is similar question:
[How do I handle animated models in Three.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16276747/how-do-i-handle-animated-models-in-three-js)